# tensorflow keras model for solving simple equation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to understand how to create a simple tensorflow 2.2 keras model that can predict a simple function value:

```
f(a, b, c, d) = a < b : max(a/2, c/3) : max (b/2, d/3)
```

I know this exact question can be reduced to a categorical classification but my intention is to find a good way to build a model that can estimate the value and build more and more functions  based on that with a more and more complex conditions later on.
For start I am stumbled upon understanding why a simple function works that hard.

For using with tensorflow on a created model I have:

```py
def generate_input(multiplier):
    return np.random.rand(1024 * multiplier, 4) * 1000


def generate_output(input):
    def compute_func(row):
        return max(row[0]/2, row[2]/3) if row[0] < row[1] else max(row[1]/2, row[3]/3)

    return np.apply_along_axis(compute_func, 1, input)


for epochs in range(0, 512):
    # print('Generating data...')
    train_input = generate_input(1000)
    train_output = generate_output(train_input)

    # print('Training...')
    fit_history = model.fit(
        train_input, train_output,
        epochs=1,
        batch_size=1024
    )
```

I have tried with different models that are less or more complex but I still didn't got a good conversion.
For example a simple liniar one:

```py
input = Input(shape=(4,))
layer = Dense(8, activation=tanh)(input)
layer = Dense(16, activation=tanh)(layer)
layer = Dense(32, activation=tanh)(layer)
layer = Dense(64, activation=tanh)(layer)
layer = Dense(128, activation=tanh)(layer)
layer = Dense(32, activation=tanh)(layer)
layer = Dense(8, activation=tanh)(layer)
output = Dense(1)(layer)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=mean_squared_error)
```

Can you give point to the direction one should follow in order to solve this type of conditional functions?

Or do I miss some pre-processing?

Comment: AFAIK, no one uses `activation=tanh` nowadays for the intermediate layers - `relu` and its variants reign.

Comment: Your inputs seem to be in the range of [0, 1000). Try pre-processing them, or removing the multiplication by 1000 in `generate_input`. I got better results with inputs in [0, 1).

Answer (score 1):

1. In my honest opinion, you have a pretty deep model, and therefore, you do not have enough data to train. I do not think you will need that much deep architecture.
2. Your problem definition is not what I would have done. You actually do not desire to generate the max value at the output, but you want the max value to get selected, right? If it is the case, I would go with a multiclass classification instead of a regression problem in my design.  That's saying, I would go with an `output = Dense(4)(layer,activation=softmax)` as the last layer and in my optimizer, I would use a categorical cross-entropy.  Of course, in the output generation, you need to manage to return an array of 3 zeros and one 1, something like this:

def compute_func(row):

```
ret_value=[0,0,0,0]
if row[0] < row[1]:
    if row[0] < row[2]:
        ret_value[2]=1
    else:
        ret_value[0]=1
else:
    if row[1]< row[3]:
        ret_value[3]=1
    else:
        ret_value[1]=1
    
return ret_value
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  

1. You can have a simpler model model, of course. Conversion will not be better :)
You can generate how much data you want. I use that in a loop to always have new data to avoid having Dropout layers.

2. I start with the assumptions that I don't know the function before and it can vary quite much how it is computed. I'll change the question a bit so that it looks clear that I don't categorical classification.

Comment: I totally understand if you want to stick to the regression. The thing is, why you have so many layers. Do you really need such a deep network? It does not seem to be a very complicated problem, you are dealing with almost 12K of parameters here. It is not actually about having enough data to train only, it is about going from small to large only if needed. After all that is my opinion, i am curious to know how you get this solve. Best of luck